# How to check String equality in Google Truth assertions?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, assertion, google-truth

`Truth.assertThat(actual).matches(expected)` or `Truth.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected)` ?

The [docs](https://truth.dev/api/latest/index.html?overview-summary.html) say that the matches() method takes in a String in the form of a regex but not sure if a string literal works as well? That's what got me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `isEqualTo(expected)`, which performs an exact equality assertion.

As you say, `matches` accepts a regex, which lets you do things like `assertThat("foo").matches("f.*")`. But regexes can interfere with exact matching. For example, `assertThat("$5").matches("$5")` will fail because the `$` in the regex means "end of string." But `assertThat("$5").isEqualTo("$5")` will pass.

Comment: Yeah I opted for using isEqualTo() because I noticed matches() was failing for strings with special characters that I suppose where being treated as part of a regex formula.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. I filed https://github.com/google/truth/issues/783 for us to improve the failure message when people use `matches` but they probably want `isEqualTo`.